# Double for loop giving unexpected answer

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I have tested this example on both Python and JS, and since the result is the same only the former will be provided. Consider the snippet

```
a = []
b = []

for i in range(3):
   for j in range(2):
      a.append(0)
   print("a = ",a)

   b.append(a)
   print("b = ",b)
```

When done using `a` as a list, the result is `[[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]`. If `a` is a string,

```
a = ""
b = []

for i in range(3):
   for j in range(2):
      a+= "0"
   print("a = ",a)

   b.append(a)
   print("b = ",b)
```

which gives `['00','0000','000000']`.

When writing the code using *lists*, I was expecting the output `[[0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]`, similar to that of *strings* but in the shape of a list. I've been trying to wrap my head around this, but to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at mutable and inmutable objects in python

Comment: In the first code you're putting the same list `a` into `b` multiple times, and also modifying the list `a`. In the second code you're putting different string into `b` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `a` is a list, calling `b.append(a)` appends a reference to `a` to the end of `b`. Then the next time the for loop is is run, `a` changes and so all references to `a` within `b` also change.

Unlike lists, strings are immutable so `b.append(a)` appends a copy of `a` to the end of `b`. You can change your code to `b.append(a[:])` to get the behavior you were looking for with strings, which makes a copy of `a` before appending.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the reference to the list and not the actual list. Use instead

```py
b.append(a[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that a is a reference to the same array that is used in every loop. You've appended a to b, but you then in the next iteration reference the same a array.

```
b.append(list(a))
```

This makes a copy of the array you're trying to append.

Answer (score 1):

what you are missing -> how append works and what you are appending.

you are adding a reference to the `b` ie for each iteration your b look like

```
b = [reference_to_a, reference_to_a, referemce_to_a]
```

and finally the reference to a is the latest one ie of last iteration.

ie whatever the value be of laster iterabtion it will be same as for all values.

you can verify this by checking the `id` of object in all cases.

how to solve this -> use a `deepcopy` of `a` and append that or create a new list of `a` element.

you can verify this above statement

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [1]
>>> 
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a.append(b)
>>> 
>>> a
[1, [1], [1], [1], [1]]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> b.append(2)
>>> a
[1, [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

so to solbe this use

```
a.append(deepcopy(b))
```

you can verify this as

```
>>> 
>>> a =[1]
>>> b = [1]
>>> 
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> 
>>> a.append(deepcopy(b))
>>> a
[1, [1]]
>>> b
[1]
>>> b.append(3)
>>> a
[1, [1]]
>>> b
[1, 3]
>>> a.append(deepcopy(b))
>>> a
[1, [1], [1, 3]]
>>> b.append(5)
>>> a
[1, [1], [1, 3]]
>>> a.append(deepcopy(b))
>>> a
[1, [1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 5]]
```